# how to edit footer in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, footer

I can't seem to find where to edit this:

http://snag.gy/e9xbd.jpg

I couldn't find anything in CMS -> Pages / Static Blocks with these hyperlinks circled in red.

Where do you edit these?

Comment: http://x3.cdn03.imgwykop.pl/c3201142/comment_4Wv1hFgneUpZo1JaQC0UvZaBYJURxS9v.jpg

Answer (score 3):

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\template\links.phtml

or this was define on page.xml

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
```

**IF u want remove link from footer just go related xml and remove from footer_links reference.**

> rss link remove from **rss.xml**
>
> search link remove from **catalogsearch.xml**
>
> contact link remove from **contacts.xml**
>
> Order return link remove from **sales.xml**

See this reference on .xml file and make comment which u not want there.

```
<reference name="footer_links">
```

**OR**

[**Using local.xml**](http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/editing-magentos-footer-links)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're on Magento 1.9? This appears to be the base theme now 1.9's default theme "RWD". For the base theme `magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml` is where this block is called. You **should not**, however, directly edit this file - but instead properly extend the theme using Magento's design fallback architecture. See more about it here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want your code to stick even after upgrading, then don't edit the files directly as they will be over-written every time you upgrade magento.

Now, to remove the links from footer:

Create a file names **local.xml** under your **package/theme** directory (if its not there already) and add the following lines in the **default** node

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <remove name="footer_links" />
    </reference>
 ...
```

Or you can check the individual concerned files and comment out the lines that add the links to the footer but then again its not advisable to edit the core files directly.

Answer (score -1):

this links are stored not in admin area - they are in design layouts in many different files

looks like you use default theme. so this links are in files under app\design\frontend\default\default - here many xml configuration files and this links are from different modules and stored in this files